# Styling Overlapping Events in Kendo UI for React Scheduler

Tags: kendo-scheduler, kendo-react-ui

I'm working with the Kendo UI for the React Scheduler component and trying to implement a visual distinction for overlapping events. I want to stack overlapping events on top of each other and apply a specific CSS class or style to those overlapped events.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

When two or more events share the same time slot, I want them to be visually stacked on top of each other.
I would like to apply a unique CSS class or style to the overlapped events to differentiate them from non-overlapping events.

Here's an example scenario:

```
Event A: 08:00 AM - 10:00 AM
Event B: 09:30 AM - 11:00 AM
```

In this scenario, Event A and Event B share the time slot from 09:30 AM to 10:00 AM. I would like to style them so that they visually overlap.

The events should look something like below. (Note: The image is only about showing the expected output. Please ignore the details inside the event)

[image]

Can anyone provide guidance on how to approach this problem? Are there any specific properties or methods in the Kendo UI for React Scheduler that I can use to achieve this styling behavior? I would greatly appreciate any insights or code examples that could help me achieve the desired result.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!